# Odoo translations are loaded but not updated

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have a module that I want to change the translations. The new translations are loaded correctly into the database but inside the form view they are not being updated. It is a selection field that I want to translate. What could be possibly the problem here? The selection field looks like this:

```
    picking_state = fields.Selection(
        string="Picking status",
        readonly=True,
        compute='_compute_picking_state',
        selection='get_picking_state',
        store=False,
        help="Overall status based on all pickings"
    )

    @api.model
    def get_picking_state(self):
        return [
            ('draft', _('No Delivery')),
            ('cancel', _('Cancelled')),
            ('not_received', _('Not Received')),
            ('partially_received', _('Partially Received')),
            ('done', _('Transferred')),
        ]
```

One sample translation that is not working for example:

```
#. module: module_name
#: code:addons/module_name/models/sale_order.py:14
#, python-format
msgid "Not Received"
msgstr "Nicht versendet"
```

The line inside the python is correct for all translations of this selection field. I also deleted all translations and loeaded them back in with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, just for people that stumble upon this:

Make sure that you define your translations (msgid) inside a module uniquely. In my example there was another module that had the same translations, the same field, and the same method for the selection just for antoher object. It assigned the translations from the other module instead of the translation of modul_name.